# Drag and Drop <div> element without dragging the content inside it | Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have one use-case which requires "[Drag-n-Drop](https://web.dev/drag-and-drop/)" API. I want to drag one div to another but the content/text inside that should not get dragged along with the .
example:

```
<div class="dropzone">
    <div id="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('',null)">
        This div is draggable // ----> this should not get draggged when this div gets dragged.
    </div> </div> <div class="dropzone"></div> <div class="dropzone"></div> <div class="dropzone"></div>
```

Comment: I believe this is a simple parent/child relationship. If the parent is draggable, all of its children come along for the ride. If you want to achieve an effect where only the box moves, you'll want to clone an identical div inside of the parent and set that to be draggable.

Comment: @cngodles can you explain a little more with code or any reference link to support your answer?

Comment: It's so much code, just more so the theory behind doing anything with an element. Its children are automatically included and brought along for the ride. You could use something like jQuery UI's drag & drop methods, these would allow you to specify exactly what the item that is getting dragged looks like.